# How should Symfony services be wrapped?

Tags: symfony, caching, dependency-injection

My application requires a cache warmer, but to make things interesting, this cache warmer is dependent upon the Symfony route cache warmer.

Before routes can be loaded, my own code needs to be run, then after loading, I need to perform more actions on the generated route names. For this to work, I need to wrap the built in route warmer with my own implementation.

Replacing the original service is simple, but how do I inject that service into my replacement?

The built in class has the `router` service injected into the constructor. If I replicated this (call `new RouteCacheWarmer`) in my own code, it may break 3rd party bundles which have also replaced the service. Aliasing the service to my own, may also break if another bundle does the same.

My aim is to run my own cache warmer, in place of the route cache warmer, but run the existing warmer from within my own. While at the same time playing nice with other bundles that may have modified the built in service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Symfony added this functionality in version 2.5. It is known as [service decoration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#decorating-services).

```
bar:
    public: false
    class: stdClass
    decorates: foo
    arguments: ["@bar.inner"]
```

This sets the `bar` service as an alias to `foo` while at the same time renames the `foo` service to `bar.inner` making it available for injection. When 3rd party bundles replace the `foo` service, the changes it made should not effect the `bar` service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a chained router, so that you leave the Symfony router doing its own thing, and then run your router entirely separately. The Symfony CMF offers such functionality in the [RoutingBundle component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/routing/introduction.html).

Comment: I did look at the CMF bundle at the time. It replaces the `Router` class and not the `RouteCacheWarmer`. Basically, it creates routes at run time whereas the cache warmer only does it a warmup time. Using their approach would cause too much of an overhead on each request.

Comment: That's the DynamicRouter part of the bundle, but I was referring to the ChainRouter service. It allows you to include multiple routers and compiles all the routes into one RouteCollection. Of course, you could take the [ChainRouter source](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/Routing/blob/master/ChainRouter.php) without taking the whole component.

Comment: I see what you're suggesting, but it doesn't answer the question. To use a chained route warmer, I still need to inject the existing warmer service into my own then replace the existing. I can do that in a compiler pass, but what if another bundles compiler pass also wants to replace the service, depending on pass order, one of the modified services would be deleted.